# Parsing an unnamed JSON array into React component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js

Beginner question again here.
I am trying to parse this JSON array :

```
[
  {
    "asset_id": "DOGE",
    "name": "DogeCoin",
    "type_is_crypto": 1,
    "data_start": "2014-02-21",
    "data_end": "2021-02-13",
    "data_quote_start": "2014-07-31T13:05:46.0000000Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2021-02-13T18:11:23.9210000Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2014-07-31T13:05:46.0000000Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:37:58.7197513Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2014-02-21T05:16:16.8330000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2021-02-13T18:12:51.7190000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 5087,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 2344753752.07,
    "volume_1day_usd": 90403357198.90,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 12757493880306.16,
    "price_usd": 0.06774975,
    "id_icon": "63e240f3-047f-41c7-9179-6784bc719f63"
  },
  {
    "asset_id": "ADA",
    "name": "Cardano",
    "type_is_crypto": 1,
    "data_start": "2017-09-29",
    "data_end": "2021-02-13",
    "data_quote_start": "2017-09-29T07:11:06.6463948Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2021-02-13T18:11:58.5984612Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2017-09-29T07:11:06.6463948Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:37:58.7010000Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2017-10-01T20:08:31.0000000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2021-02-13T18:12:42.5550000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 291,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 115032462.37,
    "volume_1day_usd": 3962452344.40,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 147189367042.86,
    "price_usd": 0.873287,
    "id_icon": "2701173b-1b77-40f2-8693-9659359e225c"
  }
]
```

for a Chart.js bar chart. I need to split up the "asset_id" and "price_usd" for use as the variables labels and data respectively shown in the example below (I.E replace the months in labels array with "asset_id", and the array of numbers in the data array with "price_usd")

```
import React from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }
  ]
};

export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'BarExample',

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Bar Example (custom size)</h2>
        <Bar
          data={data}
          width={100}
          height={50}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Note that I am using this  chart component with react hooks. The above example is just of a working example of the chart that I am trying to implement. Here is my attempt:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './data.css';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
const fetch = () => axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets",
      "headers": {
        "X-CoinAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
      },
      "params":{
        filter_asset_id:'ADA,DOGE'

      }
    })
    .then(resp => resp.data);
const labels = []
for(var i in responseData)
    labels.push([responseData[i].asset_id]);
const data =[]
for (var i in responseData)
    data.push([responseData[i].price_usd])
const dataComplete = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My First dataset',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
          hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          data: data
        }
      ]
    };

function App() {
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('');
  
  const doFetch = () => fetch()
    .then(setResponseData)
    .catch(console.log)
  
  useEffect(doFetch, []); //only needed if you fetch on first render

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>
          Fetching Data with React Hooks
        </h1>
        <button type='button' onClick={doFetch}>Click for Data</button>
      </header>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(labels,null,'\n')}</pre>
    </div>
    <Bar
          data={dataComplete}
          width={100}
          height={50}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "asset_id": "DOGE",
    "name": "DogeCoin",
    "type_is_crypto": 1,
    "data_start": "2014-02-21",
    "data_end": "2021-02-13",
    "data_quote_start": "2014-07-31T13:05:46.0000000Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2021-02-13T18:11:23.9210000Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2014-07-31T13:05:46.0000000Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:37:58.7197513Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2014-02-21T05:16:16.8330000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2021-02-13T18:12:51.7190000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 5087,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 2344753752.07,
    "volume_1day_usd": 90403357198.90,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 12757493880306.16,
    "price_usd": 0.06774975,
    "id_icon": "63e240f3-047f-41c7-9179-6784bc719f63"
  },
  {
    "asset_id": "ADA",
    "name": "Cardano",
    "type_is_crypto": 1,
    "data_start": "2017-09-29",
    "data_end": "2021-02-13",
    "data_quote_start": "2017-09-29T07:11:06.6463948Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2021-02-13T18:11:58.5984612Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2017-09-29T07:11:06.6463948Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:37:58.7010000Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2017-10-01T20:08:31.0000000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2021-02-13T18:12:42.5550000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 291,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 115032462.37,
    "volume_1day_usd": 3962452344.40,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 147189367042.86,
    "price_usd": 0.873287,
    "id_icon": "2701173b-1b77-40f2-8693-9659359e225c"
  }
]

var labels = [];
var prices = [];

data.forEach(entry => {
    labels.push(entry["asset_id"]);
    prices.push(entry["price_usd"]);
});

console.log('labels: ', labels);
console.log('data: ', prices);
```

Comment: This is sort of half the issue. Your solution does get it formatted correctly, but Im not sure how to implement it in the react component.